# change some lowercase letters to uppercase in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, uppercase

```
index = [0, 2, 5]
s = "I am like stackoverflow-python"
for i in index:
        s = s[i].upper()
print(s)

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I understand that in the first iteration the string, `s`, become just the first character, an uppercase "I" in this particular case.  But, I have tried to do it without the "s = " , using `swapchcase()` instead, but it's not working.

Basically, I'm trying to print the `s` string with the index letters as uppercase using Python 3.X

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python, so you need to create a new string object.  One way to do it:

```
indices = set([0, 7, 12, 25])
s = "i like stackoverflow and python"
print("".join(c.upper() if i in indices else c for i, c in enumerate(s)))
```

printing

```
I like StackOverflow and Python
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution. It doesn't iterate over every character, but I'm not sure if converting the string to a list and back to a string is any more efficient.

```
>>> indexes = set((0, 7, 12, 25))
>>> chars = list('i like stackoverflow and python')
>>> for i in indexes:
...     chars[i] = chars[i].upper()
... 
>>> string = ''.join(chars)
>>> string
'I like StackOverflow and Python'
```

Comment: you don't need `set()` in this case. `string = list(..)` is misleading, you could use `chars` (less misleading).

Comment: True. I actually optimized the solution and converting to a list is no longer needed. Thanks, though. :)

Comment: And yes, using set is unnecessary but what if the OP want to add an index? A set would make sense for this purpose.

Comment: 1. from `MutableString` docstring: *A faster and better solution is to rewrite your program using lists.* 2. `indexes = [0, 2, 5]` ... OP want to add an index ... `indexes.append(1)`.

Comment: But if an index already exists, you're doubling the work for that index. It just makes sense to use a set. From `set`'s docstring: "Build an unordered collection of unique elements." It doesn't need to be ordered and every index should be unique since it wouldn't make sense to have duplicates.

Comment: Rolled back. I found some benchmarking and this looks to be quickest.

Comment: imagine you use `.swapcase()` instead of `.upper()` then `list()` and `set()` indexes yield different results. btw, `string = ''.join(string)` looks awkward `string = ''.join(chars)` might be better in this case.

Comment: Why use `swapcase()` when you're specifying the indexes to be capitalized? Why would you add an index a second time to practically remove it? It's semantically incorrect and `set` is the proper data structure. As far as changing, the name of the variable, done. Thanks. :)